# cannot get a full text message through rn4020 from android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am having the same problem trying to connect with the rn4020 with MDLP bluetooth.

I am not intentionally bonding with it and did that on purpose so bonding was not necessary. You can set up the rn4020 so that it does not have to be bonded.

If I send out a text message to the rn4020 I get the first 20 chars of my message through the rn4020 and then I get the ConnParam: 0006,0000,07D0 after the 20 chars. If I send out more than 20 chars I only get the first 20 chars and the same ConnParam: 0006,0000,07D0.

I was previously having no problems and could send a message as long as 80 chars and see them at the output of the rn4020. I know mdlp limits you to 20 chars at a time but I sequentially sent 20 chars 4 times to get the 80 chars.

Comment: I am now not getting the ConnParam:0006,0000,07D0 but am still only getting a message out of the rn4020 of 20 chars BUT every once in a while I get more than 20 chars (erratic). I wonder if google developers are trying different attempts at solving this kind of problem?? If not the problem I have keeps changing!!!

Comment: I know the problem is not the rn4020 because it is still stuck in my routine looking for the next char.